# 'update_slot' is not exported by node_modules\svelte\internal\index.mjs - Sapper, Swiperjs

Tags: svelte, swiper.js, sapper

I am trying to improve Swiper.js components in Svelte, Sapper (https://swiperjs.com/svelte) but I am getting below error:

'update_slot' is not exported by node_modules\svelte\internal\index.mjs

Swiperjs version: 6.4.15

Code:

```
 <Swiper
    spaceBetween={50}
    slidesPerView={3}
    navigation
    pagination={{ clickable: true }}
    scrollbar={{ draggable: true }}
    on:slideChange={() => console.log('slide change')}
    on:swiper={(e) => console.log(e.detail[0])}
  >
    <SwiperSlide>Slide 1</SwiperSlide>
    <SwiperSlide>Slide 2</SwiperSlide>
    <SwiperSlide>Slide 3</SwiperSlide>
    <SwiperSlide>Slide 4</SwiperSlide>
    ...
  </Swiper>
  <script>
  // import Swiper core and required modules
  import SwiperCore, { Navigation, Pagination, Scrollbar, A11y } from 'swiper';

  import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/svelte';

  // Import Swiper styles
//   import 'swiper/swiper.scss';
//   import 'swiper/components/navigation/navigation.scss';
//   import 'swiper/components/pagination/pagination.scss';
//   import 'swiper/components/scrollbar/scrollbar.scss';
import "swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css"

  // install Swiper modules
  SwiperCore.use([Navigation, Pagination, Scrollbar, A11y]);

  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved after updating svelte.